# what search Algorithm does windows explorer(or other search tools) use?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, windows-explorer

It seems it can create index.

does windows explorer or word or other editor(like eclipse,notepad++,find command) use the same search Algorithm ?

Comment: the search functions on your text editors probably use a [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)

Comment: The filesystem searching in windows explorer is different.  What indexing is, is suppose you're searching for a file called `"text.txt"`.  Windows might have an index that points to every file that begins with the letter `t`.  That way, It doesn't have to search the entire filesystem, it just searches that index.  Windows explorer might not do that exactly, but the concept is the same.

Comment: regular expression using finite automata or dictionary search (Who knows windows is not open source) :(

Comment: Are you asking how it searches for files, or how it searches for text in files? With or without indexing?

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205020/java-sort-strings-like-windows-explorer/23249000#23249000. Here a working java implementation was published by me.